# How to insert an array containing questions to an HTML form?

Tags: html, forms

I have written a JS function that has as output an array containing Strings. Now i want to make an HTML form with each string representing a question, but I do not know how that would look like?
I think this should be doable, but I do not have any experience with HTML...
Thanks for answering!

I tried to make a form but including the array elements as questions proved to be hard.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

//If i may understand your question very well, you can do that with .map() //method

example; const people = ["Dav", "Lyle", "Peter"]

const namesHtml = people.map(person=> {
return

{person}

})

//namesHtml will contain each person wraped withid "p" elements
//grab div in html

document.getElementBy("people-container").innerHtml = namesHtml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).